# I can't break the while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

```
import re
#list of user information
list_id = []
list_name = []
list_surname = []
list_age = []
list_nationalid = []
list_mail = []

class Record:

    def __init__(self,programName):
        self.programName = programName
        self.loop = True
        print("welcome {}.".format(programName))

    def program(self):
        while True: #the loop gonna keep ask if input is not a correct number 
            try:
                userInput = int(input ("what you want to do?\n1-addRecord\n2-removeRecord\n3-listRecord\n4-exitRecord\n"))
                if userInput < 5 and userInput > 0: 
                    self.menu(userInput)
                    break 
                else:
                    print("pls enter a valid number")
            except Exception :
                print("pls enter a valid number again ")

    def menu(self,userInput):
        self.userInput = userInput
        if  userInput == 1:
            print("addRecord is opening")
            self.addRecord()
        if userInput == 2:
            print("removeRecord is opening")
            self.removeRecord()
        if userInput == 3:
            print("list Record are opening")
            self.listRecord()
        if userInput == 4:
            self.exitRecord()

    def addRecord(self):
        while True:
            user_name = input("pls enter your name")
            if user_name == re.findall("[^a-z]"):
                list_name.append(user_name)
                print ("addRecord_name worked")
                break
            else:
                print ("enter a valid name")
        while True:
            user_surname = input("pls enter your name")
            if user_surname == re.findall("[^a-zA-E]"):
                list_surname.append(user_surname)
                print ("addRecord_surname worked")
                break
            else:
                print ("enter a valid surname")
        while True:
            user_age = input("pls enter your age")
            if user_age == re.findall("[^0-9]"):
                list_age.append(user_age)
                print ("addRecord_age worked")
                break
            else:
                print ("enter a valid age")
        while True:
            user_nationalid = input("pls enter your national id")
            if user_name == re.findall("[^0-9]"):
                list_nationalid.append(user_nationalid)
                print ("addRecord_nationalid worked")
                break
            else:
                print ("enter a valid national id")
        while True:
            user_mail = input("pls enter your name")
            if user_name == re.search("@" and ".com" , user_mail):
                list_mail.append(user_mail)
                print ("addRecord_mail worked")
                break
            else:
                print ("enter a valid national id")

    def removeRecord(self):
        pass
    def listRecord(self):
        pass
    def backToMenu(self):
        pass
    def exitRecord(self):
        pass

System = Record("admin")
System.program() #its for keep working `program`
```

I trying to make a program which is add/remove/list data. the  while loop which is in `program` is not breaking. even If I enter my name at addRecord function it  prints "pls enter a valid number again ". problem is not about addRecord function because I already have that problem before I write these function. any advice or explain ?

Comment: You have not given `re.findall` a string argument to search on.

Comment: If you want to test if input matches a pattern, use `if re.search(r'pattern', user_name):`

Comment: `re.findall()` requires two arguments, but you only gave one.  This causes an exception, which triggers the `except` statement in `program()`.

Comment: This is also why you should not use the general `except:`. You should use `except ValueError:`. Also, the call to `self.menu()` shouldn't be inside the `try` if you only intend that for checking the input.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. We do not offer a [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) service; it is your responsibility, before asking, to figure out **what part** of the code is **relevant to causing the problem**, and to create an example that is **focused** on the problem. For example, does the problem still occur if you only implement one menu item? What if there is only one `while True:` loop in `addRecord`? The other thing to try is **do not catch generic `Exception`**. This is hiding the problem from you.

Comment: Aside from what was already pointed out, there are many things wrong with the code. Please try to **write much less code at a time** and **make sure each part works properly** before moving on to the next step.

Comment: guys I thanks for you commends. second findall argument is solve the problem but I don't get that, the error is happened in addRecord method but it cause a exception in program. can someone explain my why? when it gives error it should stop the loop I guess ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code, however your implementation of the menu is still not the best practices.

```
import re
list_id = []
list_name = []
list_surname = []
list_age = []
list_nationalid = []
list_mail = []
class Record:

    def __init__(self,programName):
        self.programName = programName
        self.loop = True
        print("welcome {}.".format(programName))

    def program(self):
        while True: #the loop gonna keep ask if input is not a correct number 
            try:
                userInput = int(input ("what you want to do?\n1-addRecord\n2-removeRecord\n3-listRecord\n4-exitRecord\n"))
                if userInput < 5 and userInput > 0: 
                    self.menu(userInput)
                else:
                    print("pls enter a valid number")
            except Exception :
                print("pls enter a valid number again ")

    def menu(self,userInput):
        self.userInput = userInput
        if  userInput == 1:
            print("addRecord is opening")
            self.addRecord()
        if userInput == 2:
            print("removeRecord is opening")
            self.removeRecord()
        if userInput == 3:
            print("list Record are opening")
            self.listRecord()
        if userInput == 4:
            self.exitRecord()

    def addRecord(self):
        while True:
            user_name = input("pls enter your name")
            if re.findall("[^a-z]", user_name) == []:
                list_name.append(user_name)
                print ("addRecord_name worked")
                break
            else:
                print("enter a valid name")

        while True:
            user_surname = input("pls enter your surname")
            if re.findall("[^a-zA-E]", user_surname) == []:
                list_surname.append(user_surname)
                print ("addRecord_surname worked")
                break
            else:
                print("enter a valid surname")



        while True:
            user_age = input("pls enter your age")
            if re.findall("[^0-9]", user_age) == []:
                list_age.append(user_age)
                print ("addRecord_age worked")
                break
            else:
                print("enter a valid age")


        while True:
            user_nationalid = input("pls enter your national id")
            if re.findall("[^0-9]", user_nationalid) == []:
                list_nationalid.append(user_nationalid)
                print ("addRecord_nationalid worked")
                break
            else:
                print("enter a valid national id")

        while True:
            user_mail = input("pls enter your email")
            if re.search("@" and ".com" , user_mail):
                list_mail.append(user_mail)
                print ("addRecord_mail worked")
                break
            else:
                print ("enter a valid email")

    def removeRecord(self):
        pass
    def listRecord(self):
        pass
    def backToMenu(self):
        pass
    def exitRecord(self):
        pass

System = Record("admin")
System.program() #its for keep working `program`
```